# Can a linear program be optimal if its basis is infeasible?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I want to know thanks to the dual theorem wether the following basis is or isn't optimal. That is to say looking for the slack variables.

[image]

As far as the third line doesn't respect the constraints:

$$7-5/6=37/5\ge 5$$

Can I say this program is therefore not optimal?

What the rules usualy to say if a primal is optimal, feasible, bounded when knwoing the state of its dual?

Comment: If the values of the objective function of  the dual and the primal´problem are equal then the solution of the primal (dual) problem is optimal. Therefore you have to evaluate the dual problem and find the solution by using the complementary slackness theorem.

Comment: But which "third line" do you mean ? Do you mean the fourth constraint. The calculation is $7-\frac{5}{2}=7-2.5=4.5 <5 \quad \large{\color{blue}{\checkmark}}$

Comment: @callculus, god, you're right...